# How to limit tcpdump to collect data for set time. ( Only collect for 60 sec for example)

Tags: tcpdump

I am trying to run tcp dump to collect all packets for a set time ( ie: 60 seconds,) but not sure how I can achieve it captures all packets and then writes it to file.

So far I have tried:

```
tcpdump -s0 -i 0.0 -c 5 -vv -n host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -w /var/log/XXX.pcap -v
```

but don't think that is the best option.
Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> How to limit tcpdump to collect data for set time

You can combine the options `-W` (*Used in conjunction with the -G option, this will limit the number of rotated dump files that get created, exiting with status 0 when
reaching the limit.*) and `-G rotate_seconds` to that effect, i. e. change `-c 5` to `-W1 -G60`.